# Getting response from Servlet on Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I am doing a servlet call from my ajax . How i can get the response in my ajax function as a variable .

```
 function myajaxcall(name) {
     var url = "/myServlet?name="+name
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: url,
         success: function() {

            console.log("Success");
            // also i want to get response from header which i have set in my servlet class . and call a another javascript method
    // call a another javascript method by passing the response from servlet .
         }
         });
}
```

The Servlet code is  :

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
String code=request.getParameter("name")+"Hi";

 response.addHeader("code", code);


}
```

Now i want to use my "code" variable in ajax call so that i can send that to another javascript method ..

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the `success` setting for jQuery's `$.ajax()` function is a function, or array of functions, which has up to three parameters (and is subsequently passed three arguments when called after the AJAX request returns a successful response):

> success
>
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )

As you can see, the third parameter is of type [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), which has a `getResponseHeader()` function.

Something like this *should* work (though untested):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        var code = xhr.getResponseHeader('code');
        yourFunction(code);
        console.log("Success");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony . :)  Now am able to do .